# Updating a waterline model from an instance method

Tags: node.js, waterline

I am using the Waterline ORM to interface with my database.

I am extend Waterline.Collections into a new objects and assign them to a module:

```
var Waterline = require('waterline');

var User = Waterline.Collection.extend({
    ...some fields...
    attributes:{
        col_a:{
             type:'integer'
        },
        touch_user:function(){
            //   increment col_a and update in table
        }
    }
});

export = module.exports = User;
```

I query for the specific models I need to update, then manipulate them in a promise.

```
database.models.users.findAll().where({'id':1}).then(...model manipulation...)
```

There is a task I perform often, almost whenever I access the model. I would like to encapsulate this task in a function associated with the instance so I can simple call "touch_user" and the relevant fields will be updated for the model i call it on.

I am not able to access the Waterline query methods (such as .update()) from the model instance after a model is queried like so:

```
database.models.users.findAll().where({'id':1).then((user)=>{
    user.touch_user();
    //user.update    // does not work
});
```

But it is not until I query it that I retrieve the data associated with the record. 
I would like user.touch_user() to increment col_a in the users table similar to the following

```
database.models.users.findAll().where({'id':1).then((user)=>{
    user.touch_user();
    database.models.users.update(user.id, {'col_a':user.col_a+1});
});
```

The problem with the above is that the user object does not accurately reflect the update to the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was creating a class method to update the model and the instance. Not exactly what I want, but it does in a pinch to keep the model and table synced

```
var User = Waterline.Collection.extend({
    ...some fields...
    attributes:{
         col_a:{
              type:'integer'
         },
     },
     //  touch_user is a class method here
     touch_user:function(user){
         // update model instance
         user.col_a += 1;
         // update database table
         database.models.users.update(user.id, {'col_a':user.col_a).exec(function(){});
     }
});
```

Called like so

```
database.models.users.findAll().where({'id':1).then((user)=>{
    ...modify user...
    database.models.users.touch_user(user);

    ...other changes to user that have to occur here...
    database.models.users.touch_user(user);
});
```